# Using minGW not in PATH with eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt

In my professional computer, I have minGW 4.5.2 installed. Eclipse CDT works perfectly with it.
But I want to test some C++11 features. So I copied my minGW 4.8.x folder from my personal PC.

My problem is that eclipse uses libraries from the old minGW (witch is the PATH).
I'd want to set eclipse up to use the new version of minGW. 
I know how to change the g++ used for compiling/linking but not the include libraries.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

PS : I can't change the PATH in my professional computer. I run Windows 7

Comment: Create a batch script that sets PATH as needed and then launches Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a batch file the following code, assuming the MinGW you want to use is in C:\MinGW :

```
set PATH=C:\MinGW\bin;%PATH%
start eclipse.exe
```